# can i use sub script tags in handlebarsjs?

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

hai i'm using handlebarsjs for templating, i'm trying to make a script tags inside a parent script tag just like the following:

```
//the first script tags

 <script id="template" type="text/x-Handlebars-template">
 {{#each this}}
      <p>{{return property name}}</p>
  {{/each}}

   //the second script tags
    <script id="template2" type="text/x-Handlebars-template">
       {{#each this}}
         <p>{{return property name2}}</p>
       {{/each}}
     </script>
 </script>
```

is it possible?? or will i get any future problems with this?

Comment: why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @charlietfl i'm making a post and commenting system using handlebars so i have to display comments for the reasonable posts accourdingly..that's why

Comment: that doesn't explain needing to nest script tag